# Openstack octavia Provisioning status error when created loadbalancer

Tags: load-balancing, openstack, cloud-computing

recently I deploy OpenStack ussuri using `kolla-ansible` based on centos8, I activate Octavia service by enabling it on `globals.yml`, after that I created the amphora flavor, security group, image with Octavia user in service project refer to this [documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/reference/networking/octavia.html)

when I create loadbalancer, I got error log  like this

`tail -f /var/log/kolla/octavia/octavia-worker.log` >>
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/WvsM5tZPPb/

My Octavia configuration:

- `/etc/kolla/globals.yml` >> https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/BPdB5KJ9hh/
- `/etc/kolla/octavia-worker/octavia.conf` >> https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XvsfnJGFf3/

I am very grateful if anyone can help me find a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

First check if all your resources are created under Octavia user or not...that can be one of the reason which is causing booting problem